# Why is this query timing out?

Tags: graph, cassandra, datastax, gremlin

I'm trying to update a vertex and all its children. I'm not sure why it's timing out.

```
v = g.V().has('a', 'id', '1').next()"
"v.property('status', '0')"
"g.V(v).out('e').repeat(property('status', '0'))"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you want to update the vertex and all its children with "status" of "0", if so then you just need to do:

```
g.V().has('a','id','1')
  property('status','0').
  repeat(out('e').property('status','0'))
```

As to why it might timeout, you might look at your data more carefully to see if you have a cycle in there somewhere (i.e. is a child somehow pointing to an ancestor somehow?). I would consider also setting a limit with `until()` or `times()` to see if you can find out how deep the traversal is going.

Comment: Looks like the time out was happening because of my query. Once I updated to what you have, it's not timing out anymore. I wonder why that is.

Comment: well - i guess `g.V().repeat(__())` technically is an infinite loop - you kinda have the same in your traversal as you are just updating the property on the same vertex endlessly.

Comment: I'm calling repeat on the vertices / children right? Why would that be an infinite loop?

g.V(v).out('e') will give me a list of children which I can call repeat on?

Comment: no - you aren't traversing beyond just the children of the first vertex with "id" of "1". the only part in the loop of your original traversal is the call to `property()` so the first child vertex hits that `repeat()` and just endlessly updates the "status" property on that vertex and because `property()` just returns that same vertex it's sent back into the `repeat()` loop again and again and again.

Comment: note how i moved the `out('e')` inside the `repeat()` - that's the big difference. the `repeat()` actually runs out of places to go after it traverses to the last child and the loop ends. `g.V().repeat(sideEffect{println(it.get().id() + " " +  it.loops)})` with TinkerGraph would show you the endless loop pretty easily.